# Chrome unable to fetch css from s3 in service worker

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, amazon-s3, service-worker

I'm trying to make my web app work offline with service workers and ran into a strange problem.

I've defined some shell files for my app like in the [guide on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps)

```js
const cacheName = 'SiMo-v0.1';
const appShellFiles = [
  '/index.html',
  '/js/build/map.c6393552f9958cd32710.js',
  'https://intermaps-lynx.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/css/menu.css',
];

self.addEventListener('install', (e) => {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Install');
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then((cache) => {
      console.log('[Service Worker] Caching all: app shell and content');
      return cache.addAll(appShellFiles);
    }),
  );
});
```

Installing that service worker fails because I get a CORS error for the css file from S3. I have already confirmed that my CORS settings on the bucket are correct and I have also tested in Firefox where the code seems to work.

Additionally I also tried running `fetch('https://intermaps-lynx.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/css/menu.css')` from the developer tools. Which failed in Chrome but also works in Firefox

**Edit:**
As suggested in the comments I have included an actual CSS file used in the site in the post.
https://intermaps-lynx.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/css/menu.css

Comment: i would suggest to start by sharing the url to your css file, its hard to judge like this, anyway assuming, you are on new firefox version and have not disabled cors security, then if a fetch failed in chrome because of cors, then it will also fail on firefox

Comment: Do you store js and css in the same place?
I suppose you need to configure CORS for your JS host, not for css.

Comment: @ehab I have included an actual CSS file used in the site in the post. I use the latest firefox and haven't disabled anything in the settings. I only allowed serviceworkers without https for my local host

Comment: @OleksandrBlyzniuk only the css files that rarely change are on the S3 JS is on the same host as the rest of the site. I don't know what you mean by configuring CORS for my JS host. It works for JS on my host and not for CSS on S3

Comment: @Eschon the css file that u have here is not configured to be fetched from cross origins, to make sure that a file is accessible from cross origins you have to add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*" to your response headers to every file that will be used by your pwa (unless its same origin)

Comment: @ehab as mentioned in the post the CORS settings are set in my S3 bucket. Otherwise it wouldn't work in firefox

Comment: If the file u just shared is from your bucket, then cors settings are not set, because I don't see the header Acess-control-allow-origin in the response

Comment: @ehab have you checked in Firefox? Unless I'm missing something the CORS settings are clearly there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly changed but I was doing some more tests and suddenly the files from S3 just work. I didn't change anything about my Bucket so there was either a fix on the side of Chrome or S3.

Anyways thanks to all the people trying to help

Answer (score 1):

**[Improvement]**

**For CORS**
As the error message shown on chrome, adding { mode: 'no-cors' } in the request option can make chrome success.

```
fetch('https://intermaps-lynx.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/css/menu.css', {
    mode: 'no-cors'
})
```

See more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

**[Remark]**

- I fetch 'https://MY_BUCKET.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/css/styles.css'
  would always respond 301 even chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, no-cors indeed makes the fetch request succeed. However the fetch request is only made as a test for the file. It doesn't help with the problem that cache.addAll can't fetch the file.

Comment: The url in your remark is not a real url. I had that one in place of my actual url before I edited my post

Comment: I'm not sure what this should do for my case? How will a technique used to prevent caching help my ServiceWorker cache files?

Comment: Okay, I misunderstand your problem, you want to keep cache?

Comment: Yes, I want to make the site work offline with a ServiceWorker

Comment: Do you use chrome on PC to open your PWA ? 
Do you enable the "Desktop PWAs local updating" on your chrome? Or maybe manifest problem.....Is there any more advanced information you can provide, for example, Github or complete demo code?

Comment: I use Chrome on Mac. The site is not installable yet, I have no manifest I only added a ServiceWorker that works aside from the Problem with the CSS files on S3. I can maybe set up a demo that I can share on Github later this week